# Separator attribute not working in SolPartMenu on DotNetNuke skin.ascx

Tags: dotnetnuke, ascx, skin

I can get rootmenuitemlefthtml and rootmenuitemrighthtml to emit but not separator. Tried CDATA wrapping and setting SeparatorCssClass. I just want pipes between root menu items.

```
<dnn:SOLPARTMENU runat="server" id="dnnSOLPARTMENU" Separator="<![CDATA[|]]>" SeparatorCssClass="MainMenu_SeparatorCSS"
        usearrows="false" 
        userootbreadcrumbarrow="false" usesubmenubreadcrumbarrow="false"
        rootmenuitemlefthtml="&nbsp;&lt;span&gt;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;" rootmenuitemrighthtml="&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&lt;/span&gt;" rootmenuitemcssclass="rootmenuitem"
        rootmenuitemselectedcssclass="rootmenuitemselected" rootmenuitembreadcrumbcssclass="rootmenuitembreadcrumb"
        submenucssclass="submenu" submenuitemselectedcssclass="submenuitemselected" submenuitembreadcrumbcssclass="submenuitembreadcrumb"
        CSSNodeSelectedRoot="rootmenuitembreadcrumb" CSSNodeSelectedSub="submenuitembreadcrumb"
        MouseOverAction="False" MouseOutHideDelay="0"
        delaysubmenuload="true" level="Root" />
```

Answer (score 2):

While not a direct answer - you might want to shift to the DotNetNuke menu rather than using SolPart.  SolPart is no longer officially supported and development work on this menu ceased almost two years ago.  Jon Henning, the author of SolPart, wrote the DotNetNuke menu from the ground up and tried to address many of the shortcomings in the original SolPart menu.

Answer (score 0):

Check this for Solpartmenu:

```
<dnn:SOLPARTMENU runat="server" ID="dnnHorizontalSolpart" ProviderName="SolpartMenuNavigationProvider"
    ClearDefaults="True" MenuBarCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_bar" MenuContainerCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_container"
    MenuItemCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_rootitem" MenuItemSelCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_itemhoverRoot"
    MenuIconCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_icon" MenuBreakCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_break"
    SubMenuCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_submenu" SubMenuItemSelectedCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_subselected"
    CSSNodeSelectedRoot="Hmain_dnnmenu_rootselected" MenuEffectsMouseOverDisplay="None"
    Separator="|" SeparatorCssClass="Hmain_dnnmenu_separator" UseArrows="False" UseRootBreadCrumbArrow="False" />
```

```
.Hmain_dnnmenu_separator
{
    background-color: Transparent;
    color: #C55203;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_bar
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: Transparent;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_container
{
    background-color: Transparent;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_rootitem
{
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    color: #C55203;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    _height: 30px;
    _padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration:underline;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_rootitem td
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    _height: 30px;
    _padding: 5px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_itemhoverRoot
{
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    color: #C55203;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    _height: 30px;
    _padding: 5px;
    text-decoration:underline;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_icon
{
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_submenu
{
    background-color: #DBDBDB;
    border: solid 1px #B7B7B7;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    color: #C55203;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration:none;
    z-index: 1000;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_submenu td
{
    border-bottom: solid 1px #B7B7B7;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
    text-align: left;
    text-decoration:none;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_break
{
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_rootselected
{
    color: #C55203;
    cursor: pointer;
    cursor: hand;
    font-size: 11px;
    font-weight: lighter;
    font-style: normal;
    font-family: Arial;
    white-space: nowrap;
    vertical-align: middle;
    text-decoration: None;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_submenu_itemhover
{
    background-color: #C55203;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
}
.Hmain_dnnmenu_subselected
{
    background-color: #C55203;
    color: #FFFFFF;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 11px;
}
```